# OpsHub VSO Migration Utility Error - could not initialize a collection

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

When I try to see migration progress in the utility I now get an error.  It is showing this for all migrations I have set running.  I have tried rebooting the machine but same error, as below.  Thanks in advance for any help.

[See this link to a screenshot of error: could not initialize a collection: [com.opshub.dao.eai.EAIIntegrationsContext#1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1Ji.png)

Comment: Can you share the migration logs? It locates at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs folder.

Comment: Hi John, Can you please mail following information at support@opshub.com and our agent would contact you for the issue you are facing.
1. Logs: Please go to <Utility Installation directory>/logs/ and send us OpsHub.log and OpsHubTFSService.log.
2. Utility version: Please click on About link on the left panel and send us the screen shot of the that About pop up.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations how I can get hold of someone about the Commercial Utility?  I have been waiting 2 days since sending the details of my projects across, and I'm very keen to progress.  Support from you has been good on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to get in contact with your company otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey John, Please share the log excerpts over here or mail them to support@opshub.com.